# running a cron job just once

Tags: java, google-app-engine

how can we schedule a cron job to run just once on google app engine for java?

i tried to set a very large value like every 1000 years but doesnt seems to work.

any other option? syntax used is:

```
  <cron>
    <url>/AdHocScriptJob</url>
    <description>Run adhoc script</description>
    <schedule>every 200 minutes</schedule>
    <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
  </cron>
```

i tried to look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Comment: why even use cron or a task if you want to run it only once.  Just call the handler with wget or curl once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what task queues are for: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview

Alternatively, you may delete the cron configuration after the task executes or make your code idempotent (e.g. by mixing it with a pull queue).